# I am unable to access a variable used in my select tag from my ModalInstance controller

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I have taken the codes shared from the Modal example page and instead of an LI I have decided to use a select element. My select element has ng-model="selectedColor" in it, and I can use {{selectedColor}} all over the partial I created, however, I can not use "$scope.selectedColor" from the "Model Instance Controller" or any controller for that matter. I assume this is because something is off with $scope but I cant seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

http://plnkr.co/edit/MsNBglLJN0hWxvGZ1pj1?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that $scope.selectedColor and the selectedColor in the modal markup are two different references. For details on this, please read [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes), you will probably benefit from it as it is a common task.

Instead of writing `$scope.selectedColor`, you should make an object in your controller, then store the result in it.

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, colors) {
  $scope.colors = colors;
  $scope.o = {}
  $scope.ok = function () {
    console.log($scope.o.selectedColor, "$scope.o.selectedColor");
    $modalInstance.close($scope.o.selectedColor);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

and in the markup, refer to `o.selectedColor`.

Here is a [working version](http://plnkr.co/edit/AWPC0vqaR8XYL2Uhn76e?p=preview) of your Plunker

Comment: Ill have to read up on scopes. As of right now its confusing how I can do ng-model in any other situation and have that object exist in the controller without having to declare it first. Yet here you can simply create an object and then model bind to it yet you cant just use selectedColor.

Comment: The problem is how Javscript prototypical inheritance works. The model instance creates a child scope.